# InDesign GREP that matches select characters between two strings

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep

I am trying to typeset a dictionary, and at the end of many of the word entries, there are additional references the reader can consult.

> ...definition here.
>
> For further reference, apple; fruit; tree

I am trying to create a GREP that allows me to select all letter characters only (*not* the semicolons) between "For further reference," until the end of the line, which terminates in a carriage return. The matching characters will all be italicized. So far, I have something that will match every character (including the semicolon):

```
(?<=For further reference,)(.)*(?=\n)
```

but when I attempt to modify this to only select [a-zA-Z] the whole thing borks.

Does anyone have any tips? This is driving our team absolutely mad

---

Edit: in the same block of text (and in the same paragraph style), directly above the "for further reference,", there can also sometimes be found the text

> ...definition here.
>
> See also ORANGES; PEARS; MANGOES
> For further reference, apple; fruit; tree

The terms following "See also" should not be italicized.

I confess I am not the one doing the actual typesetting; I do web development but am asking this question for my colleague. So, my apologies if I am misusing some InDesign terminology. And for not providing the complete information from the start.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

`((?<=For further reference,)[^;]+)|((?<=;)[^;\n]+)`

### Explanation

`(` - begin subexpression

`(?<=For further reference,)` - a *Positive Lookbehind* that matches what comes after `For further reference,`

`[^;]+` - match one or more characters that isn't a `;`

`)` - end subexpression

`|` - or

`(` - begin subexpression

`(?<=;)` - a *Positive Lookbehind* that matches what comes after a `;`

`[^;\n]+` - match one or more characters that isn't a `;` or a `\n`

`)` - end subexpression

### Used as a Grep Style

[image]

### Note

You say that your text "terminates in a carriage return", but the GREP expression that partly works for you contains a *Forced Line Break* (`\n`), so that's what I've used here (although I don't understand why you would use that).

If instead you are using *Paragraph Return* (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) you can just use `\r` instead of `\n`.

### Edit due to comments

It seems that my solution interferes with other places with the same *Paragraph Style* where semicolons occurs.

How about having one *GREP Style* that applies an italic *Character Style* to `(?<=For further reference,).*` and then another *GREP Style* that cancels the italic (by applying "regular" or whatever it's called in the font in use) for `;` afterwards?

[image]

This will of course interfere with semicolons elsewhere in the paragraph which you actually *want* to be italicized.

Comment: But this will find any string following a semicolon _anywhere_, won’t it? So if there’s a semicolon somewhere in the definition itself (not unusual in dictionaries), it will match anything after that semicolon too.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for replying! This does do the job of matching the terms that we want, but yes, as Janus has said this is matching anything after a semicolon anywhere in the document.

Comment: Then give the line with "For further reference," its own paragraph style? I assumed it already had that.

Comment: I am sorry! I was incorrect; it is not matching anywhere in the document. There is text directly above that which I described that is also picking up the italicized behavior, and _is_ a part of the same paragraph style. Please see the edit above, and thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's just really hard to answer GREP questions in general without knowing exactly how the whole document is set up. I gave it another go...